# Imposing constraints to NMinimize/NMaximize leads to wrong function values

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I wrote a function that uses `NMaximize` to find certain parameters (using NelderMead simplex algorithm). My objective functional $J({x_i})$ is real-valued and its values can only be between 0 and 1, i.e. $0 \leq J({x_i}) \leq 1 \quad \forall i$.

If I start the bare NelderMead algorithm without constraints on my parameters everything works fine, although the obtained parameters sometimes are not feasible for the underlying model. That is why I am imposing constraints on the parameters. For that, I call `NMinimize` as follows:

```
nbr=0;
NMinimize[
  {objective[vars], constraints}, 
  vars, 
  Method->"NelderMead",
  EvaluationMonitor :> {nbr += 1; If[Mod[nbr, steps] == 0, Print["Step: ", nbr, " ; Current error: ", objective[vars], vars], Print]}];
```

where `constraints` looks like `-1<=x1<=1&&-2<=x2<=2` for example. The problem now is that I see from the `EvaluationMonitor` of `NMaximize` that I get values larger than 1. Plugging the parameters for which I obtain the "wrong" results into my model shows that the value for those parameters `vars` is NOT larger than 1. So, how can it be that `NMaximize` produces wrong values during the algorithm if I impose constraints?

Comment: Can you post your objective function and constraints? Without them it's hard to test/repeat your problem.

Comment: As that involves solving a system of differential equations and a few functions, I will move all relevant things into a notebook and post a link to that here to maintain readability. I will do that within the next 1-2 hours.

Comment: Can you provide a simple objective function that exhibits the behavior that concerns you?

Comment: While reducing my code I must have introduced some error. So most certainly it will take longer than announced to upload and post the code here. Sorry for that!

Comment: `NMinimize `works by imposing penalties on some types of constraint violations. So it is common to have constraint violations at intermediate stages. That said, rectangular inequality constraints should not be violated (unless some variables are eliminated from equality constraints, which does not seem to be the case here).

Comment: While reducing my notebook to the relevant functions I found the error. It took a while to locate the misplaced bracket... Sorry for that. Would you suggest deleting the question? And btw, @DanielLichtblau: maybe it was not pointed out properly, but it was not about violating constraints, rather about obtaining function values that should not exist. Nevertheless, thanks for your explanation about constraint handling.

Comment: Raises the scary possibility that `NMinimize` is giving the wrong values for `objective[]` in `EvaluationMonitor`? Or was it exceeding the max possible due to an erroneous definition of `objective[]`?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau
 
It exceeded the max possible value due to an errorneous definition. Nevertheless it still seems strange to me as that only happens when I include the constraints. That's why I though it must have to do with the constraints